# Get certificate from netsh.exe

Tags: c#, .net, https, certificate

We have a WCF Service that is exposed with https. The certificate is configure in the console via

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:<port> certhash={<thumbprint>} appid={<some GUID>}
```

During startup I am doing this to check if there is **any** certificate listening configured for the port:

```
Process bindPortToCertificate = new Process();
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "netsh.exe");
var arguments= string.Format("http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0}", httpsPort);
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

bindPortToCertificate.Start();
bindPortToCertificate.WaitForExit();

var result = bindPortToCertificate.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var resultError = bindPortToCertificate.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) && 
result.Contains(httpsPort.ToString()))
```

With this result:

```
IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:54322
Certificate Hash             : yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Application ID               : {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
Certificate Store Name       : (null)
Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
Usage Check                  : Enabled
Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
Ctl Identifier               : (null)
Ctl Store Name               : (null)
DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
Reject Connections           : Disabled
Disable HTTP2                : Not Set
Disable QUIC                 : Not Set
Disable TLS1.3               : Not Set
Disable OCSP Stapling        : Not Set
```

I would like to perform some checks of the certificate (valid until, revoked, etc.), but I cannot find a good API to access the binding information. Looks like this is only available in the console. I know how to find the certificate in the certificate store, but I do not want to do string magic to extract the Certificate Hash from the output because I have to consider systems running with a different languages.

Any idea how to access the SSL Certificate bindings on a Windows machine via code?

Comment: See GitHub project : https://github.com/rpetz/SharpNetSH

Comment: @jdweng: I have tried that. It simply parses the output and then creates an object with dynamci properties. Unfortunately those are localized, tool